# Pandas Dataframe Enlargement

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following format

```
Name    Entries Price
John      2       10 
Mary      3       12
```

And I want to transform it to a dataframe where every row has entry value 1

```
Name    Entries Price
John      1       10 
John      1       10  
Mary      1       12
Mary      1       12
Mary      1       12
```

My solution to it was to iterate throughout every row in the original frame, get the total entries for that row, N, and then I append new rows N times to a new dataframe. However this is pretty in inefficient. Do you guys have any idea how to make it faster?

Answer (score 1):

Use -

```
op = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['Entries'])).reset_index(drop=True)
op['Entries'] = 1
```

**Output**

```
    Name    Entries Price
0   John    1   10
1   John    1   10
2   Mary    1   12
3   Mary    1   12
4   Mary    1   12
```